# Effect of "and" on assignment and addition

Tags: python

A line of code has tripped me up:

```
>>> i = 1
>>> j = 1
>>> i += j > 0 and i
>>> print(i)
 2
```

What is the underlying mechanic or system that makes this work? It seems like it's syntactic sugar for `i = i + i if j > 0 else i`, but that's a lot to unpack. Am I wrong? Is there another system in play I don't know?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

For clarity:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> j = 2
>>> i += j > 1 and i
>>> i
6
```

Comment: I might be easier to see what's happening if you use values other than "1" (since a reasonable programmer might assume that boolean true will be cast to 1 (whether python does that or not)), and note that `i += True` increments i by 1.

Comment: To understand why this works, look at how the following two statements evaluate: `j > 0 and 1 ## equals 1` and `j > 0 and 0 ## equals 0`.

Comment: I've added a different, non-boolean example.

Comment: @NoahBogart The example is still just as boolean.  You're incrementing i by True.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, `i = 3; i + True` is 4, not 6.

Comment: Noah, what do you *expect* your example to print?

Comment: @Robᵩ, I vaguely expected `i += True`. I forgot how `and` works with regards to what it returns, so the statement was throwing me for a loop.

Comment: @Noah yes, I completely misread your second example.  For what it's worth,you'd have the same behavior in common lisp with **(incf i (and (> j 2) i))**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it down:

```
In [1]: i = 1

In [2]: j = 1
```

Now, let's look at the expression `i += j > 0 and i`:

```
In [3]: j > 0
Out[3]: True
```

Because `j`, which is `1` is greater than `0`, this evaluates to `True`.

```
In [4]: j > 0 and i
Out[4]: 1
```

Because `j > 0` is `True`, the value of the boolean expression is the value of the right-hand side, namely `1`.

Thus, `i += j > 0 and i` simplifies to `i += i` or `i = i + i`:

```
In [5]: i += i

In [6]: i
Out[6]: 2
```

Let's also consider your second example:

```
>>> i = 3
>>> j = 2
>>> i += j > 1 and i
>>> i
6
```

For the thrid line we have these transforms:

```
i += j > 1 and i
i = i + (j > 1 and i)
i = 3 + (2 > 1 and 3)
i = 3 + (True and 3)
i = 3 + 3
i = 6
```

Comment: This makes a whole lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

In Python `and` and `or` do not return boolean values, but rather return one of the options presented to them which *evaluates* to the correct boolean value.

For example, `and` will return either the first `False` value it encounters, or the last `True` value:

```
>>> 1 and 3
3

>>> 1 and 0
0
```

Similarly, `or` will return the first True value it encounters, and otherwise return the first False value:

```
>>> 2 or 3
2

>>> 0 or 2
2

>>> False or 0
0
```

Basically, you should keep in mind that `and` and `or` do not necessarily return `True`/`False`, but return one of the elements presented to them which evaluates to `True` or `False`.